# Find $A=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\log 2^n}{3^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I can't find

> $$A=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\log 2^n}{3^n}$$

Please help me?

Comment: Is a term of that summation supposed to be
$$\frac{\log(2^n)}{3^n}$$
or
$$\quad\;\frac{(\log 2)^n}{3^n}\quad?$$

Comment: Suggestion: Use a law of logarithms and factor out $\log 2$ from the infinite sum.

Comment: I agree with @hardmath. What will be left is an "arithmetic-geometric sum", which you can evaluate.

Answer (score 10):

Here's what you would do depending on where the power is supposed to be:

$1$. If the general term is $\log(2^n)/3^n$, you have

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\log(2^n)}{3^n}=\log(2)\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{3^n}
$$ Because $1/3<1$, this series can be evaluated using the following formula:

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty nz^n=\frac{z}{(1-z)^2}
$$This formula is derived by differentiating the geometric series (and multiplying by $z$), which brings us to:

$2$. If the general term is $(\log(2))^n/3^n$, what you have is exactly a geometric series:

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(\log(2))^n}{3^n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{\log(2)}{3}\right)^n
$$ since $\log(2)<3$, we know that $\log(2)/3<1$, and so this series can be evaulated using the formula

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^k=\frac{z}{1-z}
$$